# Get middle node between two node neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find common node between two nodes. For example find B from `A -> B -> C`

A = node 1
B = node 2
C = node 3

A, B and C have common property (user_id, fullname) and relation property is KNOWS. node index is user_id.

Node related to:
A [:KNOWS] B and B [:KNOWS] C

I have A and C node id. I want find B node id. How can I do this using Cypher or neo4jphp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would really prefer to see something that you had written yourself, but I suppose sometimes that's just too much effort...

```
START a=node(1)
MATCH (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
WHERE a.user_id = ... (Explanation on what exactly should be done here was lacking)
RETURN b
```

Comment: I have tried this and it's works perfectly.

`start a=node(5),  c=node(46)
match (a)<-[:KNOWS*]-(nodeX)-[:KNOWS*]->(c) 
return nodeX as b;`

Comment: @JobaerShuman I'm glad that it's been helpful! Don't forget to accept an answer that has solved your problem (The little green check under the votes.)

Comment: any ideas with the java API?

Comment: @FranciscoSalvador Neo4j is trying to move away from the standard Java SDK, probably worth moving to cypher queries, but these can certainly be made through Java.